# Convert Excel File to CSV Then Load to SQL Table Using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl

I have a very large excel data to load to SQL table. For small data it works. However, for large data (more than 20 million records) I get the following error.

> Excel to CSV : There were errors during task validation. Excel to CSV
>   Error: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status
>   and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN". Excel to CSV: opening a
>   rowset for "Table1$" failed. check that the object exists in the
>   database. Excel to CSV:Error : SSIS  Error code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An
>   OLE DB error has occurred .Error code 0x80004005.

Comment: if you can execute it manullay in bids, then try to set 32bit on your sql job step instead.

Comment: The question I always ask is : where did the excel file come from? can it just be generated as tab delimited to save you the hassle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My package had no problem. The issue is with the excel file . For small data the extension .xlsx works ( excel 2007) . For the large data i have to convert the data to  Excel 97 version which is (.xls). Doing so help load the data

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get this error, something is wrong with the destination table. Check the existence of the table and also match of fields between source and destination.

Comment: when i execute the package locally it works ,but on a server it does not

Comment: try to rebuild the project and re-deploy it. Check the connections on the package/project and the parameters/configuration on the server. It seems that the source has an issue, so check the tab name of excel. Maybe would be a good idea use a csv with a raw file source than an excel file.

Comment: Everything is matching in my data  flow. i even checked the data type of source and destination .

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45049031-ad32-4500-baeb-96ff91c50663/sql-2008-ssis-importing-excel-2003-spreadsheets-silent-errors?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: For excel file with a larger data use the following link for helpful information .

Comment: http://www.alankoo.com/2012/09/strange-error-loading-excel-files-xlsx.html